# how could I retrive all available themes name programmatically

Tags: asp.net

I want to retrieve all theme names programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code. it should help you.

```
 string dirPath = Server.MapPath( HttpRuntime.AspClientScriptVirtualPath + @"/App_Themes");

System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

List<string> result = new List<string>();
if (di.Exists)
{
                foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    list.Add(dir.Name);
                }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Copied from Source](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29170780/api-to-get-all-themes-fro.aspx)

```
public static string[] GetThemes() {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["SiteThemes"] != null) {
        return (string[])HttpContext.Current.Cache["SiteThemes"];
    } else {
        string themesDirPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes");
        string[] themes = Directory.GetDirectories(themesDirPath);
        for (int i = 0; i <= themes.Length - 1; i++) {
            themes[i] = Path.GetFileName(themes[i]);
        }

        // cache the array
        CacheDependency dep = new CacheDependency(themesDirPath);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("SiteThemes", themes, dep);
        return themes;
    }
}
```